# Conda get path of package installation

Tags: python, conda

I'd like to find out where yaml package has been installed as Python is unable to import it after installation.

I've a conda environment in my project directory, and in the Conda install command I've also specifically specified the environment despite it already being activated:

```
$ conda list | grep yaml
yaml                      0.1.7
```

```
$ conda install yaml --prefix /home/abc/project_dir/envs/
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Am unable to find yaml though:

```
$ find /home/abc/project_dir/envs/ -name yaml 
(envs)$
```

Checking sys.path shows python is only looking in the envs path, and since yaml isn't present, the import is failing.

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'home/abc/project_dir/envs/lib/python37.zip', 'home/abc/project_dir/envs/lib/python3.7', 'home/abc/project_dir/envs/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 'home/abc/project_dir/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

I've already tried to uninstall and install it again. At this point I'd just like to understand where it's actually installed so that I can add it manually to the path.

Comment: `yaml` is a c library, did you mean to install the python library `pyyaml`?

Comment: Also, you can see which files belong to a conda package by inspecting the package metadata in the `pkgs` directory.  Try this: `cat $(conda info --base)/pkgs/yaml-0.1.7-*/info/files`.  That will show you that the `yaml` package does not contain python files, only compiled `.so` binary files.

Comment: Yes, silly me! You guys are right, I was installing the wrong package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was specifying yaml, whereas I should have been installing pyyaml:

conda install pyyaml

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the path of Python within Conda. I used

`conda info --all  | grep -i python`

In my application I got a few matches:

```
sys.executable: /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python  
conda location: /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda  
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
```

The environment variable `CONDA_PYTHON_EXE` is typical of Linux; `sys.executable` of Python. Windows and/or non-Python users may find comparable information in this way